# Unnecessary slash at the end of URL

Tags: apache, url

The problem is rather simple. I have a lot of pages with addresses like http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc. There is the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?request=$1
```

which redirects all requests not met by any file to index.php (and then I parse the request manually).

All works fine, except several pages. When I try to call them in the way I showed before, the browser seems to be redirected to the page 
http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ (note the trailing slash), which is not treated correctly. Other similar pages work well, directory "aaa/bbb/ccc" isn't present in filesystem. What can this be?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your **htaccess**

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`